# Javascript Ajax not working in IE 10

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion-10

I have two files

### 1. page.cfm

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        // document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        console.log("Response : " + xmlhttp.responseText);
        console.log("State : " + xmlhttp.readyState);
        if (xmlhttp.responseText.trim() == "true" || xmlhttp.responseText == "true  ") {
            console.log("done");
            return false;

        }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajx_page.cfm?ProdID="+ProdID, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

### 2. ajx_page.cfm

```
// logic condition, printing true or false
```

So, the problem, Ajax is working good in all browsers except Internet Explorer IE.
`xmlhttp.responseText` is always `false`, where as in other browers, its perfect.

Any clue why its happening with IE.

FYI.
I tried all modes of IE.

Comment: Why not use some framework like `jQuery`? :)

Comment: I cant use it, actually it's need to be done in pure javascript. and this code is present in a `function`

Comment: One common issue with Ajax in IE is that IE likes to aggressively cache the result so sometimes you have difficulty getting it to actually ask the server for the latest data.  You can work around the caching by adding a random parameter to the URL.  I have no idea if this is your particular issue or not, but it is a common issue in IE.

Comment: even i tried clearing caching each & everytime, infact i am using `InPrivate` browing mode.

Comment: Why don't you test the other states and status to see what happens ?

Comment: @dystroy only with `states : 3 & 4` its giving proper output of object type